# Angular 2: How to modify value in ngModelChange without disrupting validation?

Tags: angular, validation

I have created own implementation of number spinner component with input:

```html
<span ...>
<input 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control ui-spinner-input" 
    #spinnerModel="ngModel" 
    [ngModel]="parameter.value" 
    (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)"
    [spinnerValidator]="parameter" 
/>
<button ...
```

I want to modify the value of input in some cases, for example, the user enters value over maximum limit, I want to set the value to the maximum allowed. When I do this in `onNgModelChange`, there is a problem with validation.

For example, the maximum is 100, but user enters 150, this is what happens:

- `onNgModelChange` is called with argument 150
- inside `onNgModelChange` I change the value of the model to 100
- validation is triggered for value 100, the value is valid
- after `onNgModelChange` finishes, validation for value 150 is triggered and input is rendered as invalid, although in model and input there's already the value of 100, which is valid

How can I modify that value correctly?

**Edit**

There's a workaround for validation:

```js
onNgModelChange(newObj: any) {
    ...
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.spinnerModel.control.setValue(numericValue, {onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true, emitModelToViewChange: true, emitViewToModelChange: false});
    }, 0);
    ...
}
```

where `numericValue` is tampered value which should be applied.
Though there's a glitch in GUI, because at first invalid value is processed and GUI notices it for fraction of a second and just after that new/valid value is applied.